# How does the doT.js Plugin for PHPstorm work?

Tags: plugins, phpstorm, template-engine, jetbrains-ide, dot.js

I want to use doT.js-Templates in JetBrains PHPStorm.
I found a plugin on the JetBrains Plugin-Site http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7327?pr=idea for doT-Templates.

I installed it and restarted the IDE, but it doesn't seem like anything has changed.
The Github-Page or the description don't tell anything about what exactly the plugin does or how it works.

Does anyone know what this plugin does?
Or does anyone know another way for achieving syntax highlighting or IntelliSense for dotJS-Templates in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
In order for the doT-Plugin to highlight doT-Template-Sytax, I had to create files with the .dot-extension instead of the ".html" extension I had before.

But if anyone sees this and decides to use this solution, be aware that changing your .html-Files to .dot-Files wrecks PHPStorm's autocompletion of html-Code inside of these files.